# Can't connect to MAAS due to "Files does not exist: /var/www/maas" error

Tags: 12.04, 13.04, juju, maas, openstack

I have attempted to install MAAS on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and 13.04, but on both I cannot connect to the region controller via a web browser for the post installation per the http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/install.html guide.

I can connect to the default Apache webpage without issue. Reviewing the Apache error log, on both instances I see the following error:

```
[Sat May 04 20:48:53 2013] [error] [client 172.16.86.1] Files does not exist: /var/www/maas
```

I used the troubleshooting guide (http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/troubleshooting.html) but everything checked out. Is there an issue with the MAAS package / installation option?

Answer (score 1):

The URL is `http://<server>/MAAS`, not `http://<server>/maas`.

Comment: Interesting, Safari must have been changing it to lowercase whereas Internet Explorer would keep it in upper.  I am somewhat surprised it is case sensitive with the configuration...  But thanks for the clarification.